# TypeScript, why are subsequent function calls much faster than the original call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, performance

I have the following TypeScript code, which is a solution to day 3 of the 2021 advent of code challenge:

```js
import getPuzzleInput from "../utils";

function partOne(input: string[]) {
  console.time(`p1`);
  let gammaRate = ``;
  let epsilonRate = ``;
  const lengthOfInput = input[0].length;

  const zeros = Array(lengthOfInput).fill(0);
  const ones = Array(lengthOfInput).fill(0);

  input.forEach((value) => {
    [...value].forEach((bit, index) => {
      if (bit === `0`) {
        zeros[index] += 1;
      } else {
        ones[index] += 1;
      }
    });
  });

  zeros.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (value > ones[index]) {
      gammaRate += `0`;
      epsilonRate += `1`;
    } else {
      gammaRate += `1`;
      epsilonRate += `0`;
    }
  });

  const gamma = parseInt(gammaRate, 2);
  const epsilon = parseInt(epsilonRate, 2);

  console.log(`Gamma ${gamma}`);
  console.log(`Epsilon ${epsilon}`);
  console.log(`Solution ${gamma * epsilon}`);
  console.timeEnd(`p1`);
}

function calculateSums(input: string[]) {
  const sums = Array(input[0].length).fill(0);

  input.forEach((value) => {
    [...value].forEach((bit, index) => {
      sums[index] += Number(bit);
    });
  });

  return sums;
}

function partOneAlternateSolution(input: string[]) {
  console.time(`p1a`);
  const lines = input.length;
  let gammaRate = ``;
  let epsilonRate = ``;
  const sums = calculateSums(input);

  sums.forEach((value) => {
    if (value > lines / 2) {
      gammaRate += `1`;
      epsilonRate += `0`;
    } else {
      gammaRate += `0`;
      epsilonRate += `1`;
    }
  });

  const gamma = parseInt(gammaRate, 2);
  const epsilon = parseInt(epsilonRate, 2);

  console.log(`Gamma ${gamma}`);
  console.log(`Epsilon ${epsilon}`);
  console.log(`Solution ${gamma * epsilon}`);
  console.timeEnd(`p1a`);
}

export default function runDay() {
  const input = getPuzzleInput(`day3`);
  partOne(input);
  console.log(`---`);
  partOne(input);
  console.log(`---`);
  partOne(input);
  console.log(`---`);
  partOneAlternateSolution(input);
  console.log(`---`);
  partOneAlternateSolution(input);
  console.log(`---`);
  partOneAlternateSolution(input);
}
```

When I execute this code, I get the following output (gamma, epsilon, and solution values removed):

```
p1: 3.52ms
---
p1: 0.921ms
---
p1: 0.522ms
---
p1a: 1.128ms
---
p1a: 0.485ms
---
p1a: 0.508ms
```

And if I reverse the order of the functions being called, I get this output:

```
p1a: 3.511ms
---
p1a: 1.102ms
---
p1a: 0.468ms
---
p1: 1.046ms
---
p1: 0.567ms
---
p1: 0.542ms
```

My question is twofold:

1. Why does the same exact function being run 3 times, get faster with each subsequent call?
2. Why does `p1` take 3.52ms to run if it's called first, but only 1.046ms if it's called after `p1a`? And the other way around with `p1a` being called first and `p1` after.

[Puzzle input, to run the code yourself if necessary.](https://pastebin.com/cCvYgz3g)

Comment: Optimizing interpreters do all sorts of run-time optimizations when they find a repeated code path. It wouldn't surprise me if V8 was doing something like that here.

Comment: Also, do multiple measurements if you need statistically significant results, e.g. benchmark.js. What you observe here is a way an engine works. Can also try this in a browser (FF) and see if the picture changes